# How to store cost data in Meteor JS so it can be incremented?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of services with associated costs and time it takes to complete the service. When I save them in the database, the object looks like this:

```
cost: "1"
name: "Yawn"
time: "10"
```

I believe the parentheses around the numbers aren't allowing my app to increment these objects when I call them in a Meteor Method.

I keep receiving this error on insert:

```
> errorClass {stack: "Error↵    at m.(anonymous function) (http://localh…7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:3735:17)", error: 409, reason: "MinimongoError: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number"
```

Services are added using this function:

```
Meteor.methods({
createService: function(postAttributes) {
var user = Meteor.user();

// ensure the user is logged in
if (!user)
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new stories");

// ensure the post has a title
if (!postAttributes.name)
  throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a name');

    // ensure the service has a cost
if (!postAttributes.cost)
  throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a cost');

    // ensure the post has a title
if (!postAttributes.time)
  throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a time');

console.log(postAttributes);

// pick out the whitelisted keys
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'name'), {
  cost: postAttributes.cost,
  time: postAttributes.time,
  userId: user._id, 
  author: user.emails[0].address, 
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
});

var postId = Services.insert(post);

return postId;
}
});
```

I'm incrementing using this function:

```
 Appointments.update(postAttributes.appointmentId, { $inc : 
  { "appointmentTotal": service.cost} } );
```

I'm completely lost in getting the cost and time for services in a number format instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you said, it seems that you just need to turn your strings into integers:

```js
var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'name'), {
  cost: parseInt(postAttributes.cost),
  time: parseInt(postAttributes.time),
  userId: user._id, 
  author: user.emails[0].address, 
  submitted: new Date().getTime()
});
```